# How to assign a specific value from an other column in pandas in a given time frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to create a rolling forecast for the following 12 months, the results for the month and entry must become part of the dataframe as well (Later it will be written out into excel as part of a bigger dataframe).

The entries for the new dataframe needs to be calculated based on the criteria, that the forecasted month is between start_date and start_date + duration is also in the range of the forecasted 12 months. If these are met, the value from duration should be written here.

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY1sR.png)

To do this I imagine that I have to use a numpy.where(), however I can not wrap my head around it.

I came across [Use lambda with pandas to calculate a new column conditional on existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534380/use-lambda-with-pandas-to-calculate-a-new-column-conditional-on-existing-column), but after some trying I came to the conclusion, that this can not be the whole truth for my case.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"]
cur_month = dt.date.today().month - 1
cur_year = dt.date.today().year

d = {'start_date': ['2020-12-23', '2021-02-08', '2021-06-11', '2022-01-07'], 'duration': [12, 6, 8, 3], 
'effort': [0.3, 0.5, 1.2, 0.1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
i = 0
while i < 12:
    # this creates the header rows for the 12 month period
    next_month = months[(cur_month + i) % len(months)]
    
    # here goes the calculation/condition I am stuck with...
    df[next_month] = np.where(...)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with this and seems to work, I also added some logic for weighting for the cases a project starts some time during the month, so we get a more accurate effort number.

```
d = {"id": [1,2,3,4], "start_date": ['2020-12-23', '2021-02-08', '2021-06-11', '2022-01-07'], "duration": [12, 6, 8, 3], 
"effort": [0.3, 0.5, 1.2, 0.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["EndDates"] = df["start_date"].dt.to_period("M") + df_["duration"]
i = 0
forecast = pd.Series(pd.period_range(today, freq="M", periods=12))

while i < 12:
    next_month = months[(cur_month + i) % len(months)]
    df[next_month] = ""

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df_tmp = df.loc[df['id'] == int(row['id'])]
        if not df_tmp.empty and pd.notna(df_tmp["start_date"].item()):
            if df_tmp["start_date"].item().to_period("M") <= forecast[i] <= df_tmp["EndDates"].item():

                # For the current month let's calculate with the remaining value
                if i == 0:
                    act_enddate = monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]
                    weighter = 1 - (int(today.day) / int(act_enddate))
                    df.at[index, next_month] = round(df_tmp['effort'].values[0] * weighter,
                                                                ndigits=2)
                # If it is the first entry for the oppty, how many FTEs will be needed for the first month
                # of the assignment
                elif df_tmp["start_date"].item().to_period("M") == forecast[i]:
                    first_day = df_tmp["start_date"].item().day
                    if first_day != 1:
                        months_enddate = monthrange(forecast[i].year, forecast[i].month)[1]
                        weighter = 1 - (int(first_day) / int(months_enddate))
                        df.at[index, next_month] = round(df_tmp['effort'].values[0] * weighter,
                                                                    ndigits=2)
                    else:
                        df.at[index, next_month] = df_tmp['effort'].values[0]
                # How many FTEs are needed for the last month of the assignment
                elif df_tmp["EndDates"].item() == forecast[i]:
                    end_day = df_tmp["start_date"].item().day
                    if end_day != 1:
                        months_enddate = monthrange(forecast[i].year, forecast[i].month)[1]
                        weighter = int(end_day) / int(months_enddate)
                        df.at[index, next_month] = round(df_tmp['Umrechnung in FTEs'].values[0] * weighter,
                                                                    ndigits=2)
                    else:
                        continue
                else:
                    df.at[index, next_month] = df_tmp['effort'].values[0]
```